# Where is the default directory of saved files using wget in crontab?

Tags: linux, wget, cron

I want to download some files using `wget` command in `crontab`. I use a text file to make a list of my desired urls. `wget`'s `-O` parameter works well for setting a destination folder for single files, but I can't find a way to set a directory for saving a list of files. I want to know where is the default directory for saving files using `crontab` and `wget`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cron` job for a user runs in that user's home directory (`$HOME`) and so that is, in effect, the "default directory" for everything which happens through `crontab`

If you want it to happen somewhere else, just say so.

```
42 3 * * * cd /tmp && $HOME/ick.sh
```

This will run `$HOME/ick.sh` with the current directory set to `/tmp` every night at 03:42.

(The commands in `crontab` could be arbitrarily complex, but it makes sense to write them into a script if they are more than just one or two commands.)